# SVG animate - how to transform scaling-point

Tags: xml, svg

i'm trying to animate the height of a rectangle from its lower edge so it scales upward over time and not downward (from its native origin)

here's the xml-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="PARENT">
    <rect id="yellow_rect" x="100" y="200" fill="#FFF80B" stroke="#020202" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="20" height="20"/>
</g>
<g id="CHILD">
    <rect id="red_rect" x="77.047" y="16.375" fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="45.906" height="183.625">
        <animate attributeName="height" attributeType="XML" begin="0s" dur="2s" 
            fill="freeze" from="0" to="183.625"/>
    </rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

transform="translate ..." did not work, just placed the red rectangle somewhere else.

is there a way to scale upward?

*or*

maybe even use the yellow rectangle's position as scaling point?

*or*

use the yellow rect as a scale-parent for the red one?

can't yet wrap my head around this - i'm fairly new to SVG. any answer is appreciated!

thanks, 
sebastian

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a couple of different ways, not sure this is the best, but its one solution I think anyway. If you scale(1,-1) and adjust the rect with a translate. You could move the scale/translate to the outer  element instead I guess as well.

```
<rect id="red_rect" x="77.047" y="16.375" fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="45.906" height="183.625" 
  transform="translate(0,216.375) scale(1,-1)">
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/274vj/)

Comment: wow! that's neat! didn't expact so little changes. but how did you get that translate(0,216.375)? i mean that digit ...

Comment: sorry, got it myself. as you said: it moves the rectangle.